# How RESTful token authentication works

Tags: rest, api, http, token

I understand that i have to provide a token to a client upon a successful authentication. What i still don't understand is how a server validates the token and its expiration time.

If RESTful services are stateless, how is it possible to authenticate a token on the server? Could anyone provide examples of token validation?

Comment: Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45418306/securing-java-rest-service-json-webtoken-jwt-or-oauth-1-0/45431350#45431350

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If RESTful services are stateless, how is it possible to authenticate a token on the server?

The server stores no state, the state used to validate a token is contained inside the token e.g. an expiration date & an account ID. A very simple, pseudo, example:

```
if token.expiry < now then
   return tokenExpired
If !findUser(token.accountId) then
   return accountNotFound

return tokenOk
```

The server *may* keep track of what tokens it has issued as a security measure to ensure old tokens can't be reused, and such that tokens can't be forged. So if we take the previous example it could updated to include an additional check

```
if !tokenActive(token) then
    return tokenInvalid
```

Comment: You are performing a search for an account ID. Is it the token validation?

Comment: @DiegoVictorDeJesus well it's part of it, tokens are issued to identify a user - when validating such tokens you'd want to make sure that it still matches an active account. It may also validate other things such as account status (e.g. user could be locked out or suspended etc)

Answer (score 0):

the token contains some usefull information, like the date, some values like the username or email and others fields.

If I take for example the JWT token, you will find 3 'fields of information'
1/ header
2/ payload
3/ verify signature

You will find more datas on this website : https://jwt.io/introduction/